# Apply a ID to webgrid row

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

How to apply class to a particular column in web grid? I have to apply class to Ref Id column in the following code. AND How to apply a ID to every row & value of ID will be value of a column RefId?

```
@grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "table table-bordered",
                columns: grid.Columns(
                grid.Column("RefId", "Ref Id"),
                grid.Column("CaseDescription", "Case Description"),
                grid.Column("CreatedBy", "Created By"),
                grid.Column("CreatedDate", "Created Date")                
                ))
```

I have tried many things but didn't get it working.

Comment: Have you tried [WebGridColumn.Style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webgridcolumn.style(v=vs.111).aspx)? `grid.Column("RefId", "Ref Id", style: "RefId")`

Comment: I want to apply a class, so that i can hide the class on a Jquery event, Will the STYLE help in this?

Comment: I am stuck ahead so edited the question. Pls help me.